# Kendo templates (for a grid), allow the template access to the external 'this' pointer and the 'data' variable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a JavaScript class instance which creates a grid, one of the columns is a template function like so:

```
template: " #=that.MyTemplate(data) #",

function MyTemplate(data)
{
}
```

This doesn't work as it accesses 'that', a local pointer to the 'this' pointer of the instance of the class.

Is there any way to access the instances method while still retaining access to the local data object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only so I can find it again, closures to the rescue

```
template: (function ()
{                               
    return function (data)
    {                                   
        return that.MyTemplate(data)
    }
}()),
```